# Prove to my customers that their data in AWS is encrypted

Tags: amazon-web-services, security

I am about to launch a webapp based on subscription. FYI, the web application manages health care data, and my customers are concerned about the security of data in the cloud.
Is there any certificate, or any official information I can give to my customers on the behalf of AWS proving that the data in any storage used by my application will be encrypted?

THANK YOU

Comment: I don't think so. I think you would have to go through some third-party audit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [What is AWS Artifact?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/artifact/latest/ug/what-is-aws-artifact.html):

> **AWS Artifact** provides on-demand downloads of **AWS security and compliance documents**, such as AWS ISO certifications, Payment Card Industry (PCI), and Service Organization Control (SOC) reports. You can submit the security and compliance documents (also known as audit artifacts) to your auditors or regulators to **demonstrate the security and compliance of the AWS infrastructure and services that you use**. You can also use these documents as guidelines to evaluate your own cloud architecture and assess the effectiveness of your company's internal controls. AWS Artifact provides documents about AWS only. AWS customers are responsible for developing or obtaining documents that demonstrate the security and compliance of their companies.

It explains what AWS does. However, you would also need to prove that *you* are using the cloud correctly, such as verifying user's identities and not making buckets public.

Comment: Hi John, it's great to see that you are still active in the AWS community :)

Answer (score 0):

NO, there is no such a document, you need to apply and obtain this certificate.
AWS is complaint, for there part **Security of the cloud**, and you are responsible for the **Security in the cloud**. AWS Artifact is a repository.

- AWS Config is the tool you will use to monitor the configuration of
  your stack, can repair configurations also.
- AWS Cloudwach will monitor the performance, brings you alerts and evoke Lambda
- AWS Cloud Trail will monitor the API calls.
- AWS Macy to check your buckets for Personal Identifiable information.
  Then you are the one who enable encryption and choose the Key management and rotation, AWS KMS.

Just to mention few services to be aware of. Best regards.